# How can have an install4j installer automatically set the user's command line PATH on Linux/Mac/Windows?

Tags: command-line, path, install4j

I have some users who are uncertain about how to add my command line programs to their PATH variable on Linux and Mac (or the alternative settings on Windows).  I use install4j 10.0.6 on Mac.  I can see that the Installer, under Screens and Actions, I can add an Installation Action to the Installation group, for example "Modify an environment variable on Windows" under "Miscellaneous".  I haven't tried that yet, but is there an equivalent for Mac or Linux, an action that modifies the user's PATH in their shell's startup resources?

For example, see this install4j window:

[image: Screenshot of install4j window]

Answer (score 1):

> an action that modifies the user's PATH in their shell's startup resources?

On macOS, this would not do anything for apps started from the Finder. It is notoriously difficult to reliable set environment variables for applications on macOS, so that is not a path I would pursue.

On Linux, this could be supported, but as of 10.x this is not an available feature in install4j. Due to the flexibility in how login shells can be configured on Linux, this is also likely to not be 100% reliable.

To include an application into the PATH, another option would be to create a symbolic link in a well-known directory. /usr/local/bin would be a good candidate. Of course, you can only do that if you have admin privileges.